# Opendaylight : RemoteDevice : No more sources for schema context

Tags: opendaylight

hello im trying to connect cisco CSR1000v to opendaylight controller
im using opendaylight 0.5.2 Boron SR2 and cisco CSR1000v 15.03.05

i follow the instruction in the opendaylight netconf guide
http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-boron/user-guide/netconf-user-guide.html

i sucessfully add the device, but when i check, its error

```
"node": [
                {
                    "node-id": "CSR1K",
                    "netconf-node-topology:connection-status": "unable-to-connect",
                    "netconf-node-topology:connected-message": "RemoteDevice{CSR1K}: No more sources for schema context"
                },
```

anyone know what happen? thanks before

Comment: I've no idea what this specific message means, but you MAY be able to get help for this by posting on the netconf-dev mailing list, here: https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/netconf-dev

Comment: okey thank you, but now i have fix this issue :D

Comment: can you please post the answer, since I am facing the same issue with oxygen

Comment: just follow second instruction in the docs